# Use multiprocessing to update many dictionaries from a list

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

Can you explain why if I do this:

```py
def update_dictionary(mydict):
    mydict['sampleKey'] = 1

d = [{'test':2}, {'tast':3}]
for i in d:
    update_dictionary(i)
```

`d` gets updated

but if I do:

```py
with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    for q in pool.map(update_dictionary, d):
        print('done')
```

it won't work?

And so, how can I update all the dictionaries in the list taking advantage of multiprocessing?

Comment: @shaikmoeed This question isn't using Manager.

Comment: You should probably use multithreading instead of multiprocessing. With multiprocessing, every process has its own copy of the dictionary, you need to use `Manager()` to share the dictionary between processes. Multithreading uses the same memory in all threads.